# Bigvideo, evento ended por cada vídeo en array

Tags: videojs

Estoy usando bigvideo para poner un array de videos en el fondo

```
$(function() {
        var BV = new $.BigVideo();
        var vids = [
            '2.mp4',
            '3.mp4'
        ];
        vids.sort(function() { return 0.5 - Math.random() }); // random order on load
        BV.init();
        BV.showPlaylist(vids,{ambient:true});

        BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function () {
            // Salta cuando se reproducen todos los videos :(
        });



});
```

Quiero crear un evento cada vez que finalice uno, con el fin, de que aparezca un link diferente por cada video.

¿Cómo lo puede hacer?

Comment: Buenas Gonzalo, bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] y [ask] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio y cómo hacer mejores preguntas. No está del todo claro lo que pides. Además has de mostrar lo que has intentado y por qué no te ha funcionado: ¿fallos, errores, resultado inesperado?  Un saludo

Comment: No puedo reproducir el problema. Copiando tu código y sólo cambiando los vídeos, me funciona perfectamente y la función se lanza al final de cada vídeo y no al final del playlist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo reproducir el problema. Copiando tu código y sólo cambiando los vídeos, me funciona perfectamente y la función se lanza al final de cada vídeo y no al final del playlist.

Mirando en la [documentación](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) y en el [ejemplo que tienen para Playlist](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/example-playlist.html), parece que BigVideo.js tiene bastantes dependencias: jQuery, video.js, Modernizr, EventEmitter... Si no te funciona correctamente, puede ser porque te falte incluir alguna biblioteca.

Aquí puedes ver tu código funcionando sin problemas (sólo he cambiado la lista de vídeos y el contenido del controlador del evento `ended`):

```js
$(function() {
  var BV = new $.BigVideo();
  var vids = [
    'https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/dock.mp4',
    'https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/river.mp4',
    'https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/frontier.mp4'
  ];
  vids.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
  }); // random order on load
  BV.init();
  BV.showPlaylist(vids, {
    ambient: true
  });

  BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function() {
    // leer el atributo data-num y sumarle 1
    var num = document.getElementById("num");
    num.dataset.num = parseInt(num.dataset.num) + 1;
  });
});
```

```css
h1 {
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999;
  color:white; 
}

h1::after {
  content: attr(data-num);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/BigVideo/css/bigvideo.css" />

<!-- Dependencias -->
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/eventEmitter/EventEmitter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/eventie/eventie.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.js"></script>
    
<!-- BigVideo.js -->
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/BigVideo/lib/bigvideo.js"></script>

<h1 id="num" data-num="0">Cambios de video: </h1>
```

---

No sé cómo tenías pensado guardar los enlaces para cada vídeo, pero creo que no puede ser en un array ordenado, porque parece que desordenas los vídeos para reproducirlos. Entonces para cambiar el enlace cada vez que cambia el vídeo, podrías leer qué vídeo se está reproduciendo y dependiendo del valor, mostrar un enlace u otro.

Esto es sencillo y se podría hacer así cambiando el código para añadir un `if...else if...` así:

```js
$(function() {
  var BV = new $.BigVideo();
  var vids = [
    'https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/dock.mp4',
    'https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/river.mp4',
    'https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/vids/frontier.mp4'
  ];
  vids.sort(function() {
    return 0.5 - Math.random()
  }); // random order on load
  BV.init();
  BV.showPlaylist(vids, {
    ambient: true
  });

  BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function() {
    // leer el atributo data-num y sumarle 1
    var num = document.getElementById("num");
    num.dataset.num = parseInt(num.dataset.num) + 1;
    
    // obtenemos la fuente del vídeo
    var src = BV.getPlayer().v.src;
    var enl_nombre = "";
    var enl_link = "";
    // dependiendo del valor de la fuente elegimos un texto/enlace
    if (src.indexOf("dock") >= 0) {
      enl_nombre = "Video del dock, enlace a SOes";
      enl_link = "https://es.stackoverflow.com";
    } else if (src.indexOf("river") >= 0) {
      enl_nombre = "Video del rio, enlace a SOen";
      enl_link = "https://stackoverflow.com";
    } else if (src.indexOf("frontier") >= 0) {
      enl_nombre = "Video del frontier, enlace a Google";
      enl_link = "https://www.google.com";
    }
    // cambiamos el DOM para el enlace
    var enl = document.getElementById("enlace");
    enl.href = enl_link;
    enl.innerHTML = enl_nombre;
    console.log(enl);
  });
});
```

```css
h1, a {
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999;
  color:white; 
}

h1::after {
  content: attr(data-num);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/BigVideo/css/bigvideo.css" />

<!-- Dependencias -->
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/modernizr/modernizr-2.5.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//vjs.zencdn.net/4.3/video.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/eventEmitter/EventEmitter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/eventie/eventie.js"></script>
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.js"></script>
    
<!-- BigVideo.js -->
<script src="https://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/bower_components/BigVideo/lib/bigvideo.js"></script>

<h1 id="num" data-num="0">Cambios de video: </h1>
<a href="#" id="enlace"></a>
```

El código de arriba es sólo un ejemplo. Seguramente te interesa mover las funciones del controlador `ended` al de `play` para que se cargue el enlace y la información desde el principio y no al cambio de vídeo.